# Mule 3.4.0 Choice router based on presence of a node in payload using Xpath

Tags: xml, soap, xpath, mule

I have a couple of Soap inputs and would like to decide course of action in my Mule Flow based on existence of an Element in Payload.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xyz="http://xyz.abc.com/">
  <soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <xyz:myFirst/>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>


<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xyz="http://xyz.abc.com/">
  <soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <xyz:mySecond>
        Something here
    </xyz:mySecond>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

In the above payloads, if "myFirst" is present, I would like to go one route and if "mySecond" is present, another route.

I tried the following

```
<choice>
  <when expression="#[xpath('fn:count(//soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/xyz:myFirst/child::text())') != 0]">
    //Do something First Here
  </when>
  <when expression="#[xpath('fn:count(//soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/xyz:mySecond/child::text())') != 0]">
    //Do something Second Here
  </when>
  <otherwise>
    //Didn't match any!
  </otherwise>
</choice>
```

But "myFirst" is never identified since it is empty. I tried what is mentioned at this location [Using XPath to Check if Soap Envelope Contains Child Node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16156037/using-xpath-to-check-if-soap-envelope-contains-child-node) but to no avail. My current attempt is based on [How to tell using XPath if an element is present and non empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15909348/how-to-tell-using-xpath-if-an-element-is-present-and-non-empty) .

Thoughts?

Comment: By "present" do you mean "element present and with text content in it"?

Comment: Hi David. By present I mean, <myFirst/>, empty node is present in input. If the node has text, my expression works fine, like for <mySecond>Something here</mySecond> it works fine.

Comment: So with `<xyz:myFirst/>` you want to go there `//Do something First Here`, right?

Comment: @DavidDossot. That is correct. I will try the solution Learner has provided below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `XPath` you are testing on `child text node`, that's why it never goes on first choice element if you have an empty node in sample payload. If the intent is to perform a task even if the node is empty, do this:

```
<choice>
  <when expression="#[xpath('fn:count(//soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/xyz:myFirst)') != 0]">
    //Do something First Here
  </when>
  <when expression="#[xpath('fn:count(//soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/xyz:mySecond') != 0]">
    //Do something Second Here
  </when>
  <otherwise>
    //Didn't match any!
  </otherwise>
</choice>
```

Comment: This worked! I had tried this earlier too, but had a trailing "/" in namespace (incoming SOAP msg) and hence it was not matching the namespace in "mule-xml:namespace" :(. I probably should have pasted the namespace too. Someone would have noticed right away! Thanks!