# How to use Choice Pattern over Soap Request in Mule ESB?

Tags: soap, mule, esb

I have an endpoint accepting Soap Requests, after this endpoint, it goes to a *Transform Message* which generates the appropriate request to an external web service.
What I want to do is to use the *Choice Pattern* to decide to which external web service I must redirect.

```
<http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="0.0.0.0" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
<cxf:configuration name="CXF_Configuration" enableMuleSoapHeaders="true" initializeStaticBusInstance="true" doc:name="CXF Configuration"/>
<ws:consumer-config name="Web_Service_Consumer" service="KarmaService" port="KarmaPort" serviceAddress="http://localhost:8080/TestingWS/Karma" wsdlLocation="http://localhost:8080/TestingWS/Karma?wsdl" doc:name="Web Service Consumer"/>
<flow name="testingChoice">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <cxf:proxy-service configuration-ref="CXF_Configuration" payload="body" doc:name="CXF"/>
    <dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message">
        <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
    %output application/xml
    %namespace ns0 http://karmapackage/
    ---
    {
       ns0#sayHello: {
      arg0: payload.invoke.arg0
    }
    }]]></dw:set-payload>
    </dw:transform-message>
    <choice doc:name="Choice">
        <when expression="#[payload]">
            <logger message="Info1" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        </when>
        <otherwise>
            <logger message="Default" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        </otherwise>
    </choice>
    <ws:consumer config-ref="Web_Service_Consumer" operation="sayHello" doc:name="Web Service Consumer"/>
    <logger message="Andando" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
</flow>
```

Right now, *Choice* is redirecting to Logger info, just to know what it is doing.
I don't know how to set the *expression* on the when condition to check if *arg0* has the value *choosePath1* for example.

I would appreciate any help,
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Check this post, write xpath expression based on your transformed xml. [Mule 3.4.0 Choice router based on presence of a node in payload using Xpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19326919/mule-3-4-0-choice-router-based-on-presence-of-a-node-in-payload-using-xpath)

Also check how to build xml xpath on mule documents

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/xpath